# Why are some of the PivotTable labels showing the wrong year?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

I've got a legacy view of some data that looks like this - notice that September through December are in 2015, not 2016:

[image]

The PivotTable version of this data, though, shows *all* the years as being in 2016:

[image]

...and thus misorders them, too, with Sept-Dec coming *after* Jan and Feb because of this year-confusion.

The PivotTable is generated from source data on yet another sheet that has the same data as the "legacy" sheet (Sept-Dec = 2015, Jan and Feb = 2016):

[image]

The date vals are added from the source data to the PivotTable like so:

```
var pch = _xlBook.PivotCaches();
int pivotDataRowsUsed = xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int pivotDataColsUsed = 
    xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
string lastColWrittenAsAlpha 
    ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetExcelColumnName(pivotDataColsUsed);
string endRange = string.Format("{0}{1}", lastColWrittenAsAlpha
    pivotDataRowsUsed);

Range sourceData = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].Range[string.Format("A1:{0}", endRange)];

PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, sourceData);
PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(_xlPivotTableSheet.Range["A6"], "PivotTable");
. . .
var monthField = pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr");
monthField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
monthField.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy";
monthField.DataRange.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightBlue);

pvt.CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "Months";
```

The Sept, Oct, and Nov rows above what's seen above are all "15-"; all the Jan and Feb are "16-"

So why are the date labels showing "16" in all cases, instead of being sometimes "15", and how can I get them to display aright?

### UPDATE

Even worse is when I run the report for the typical 13 months, thus having two of the same months (but from two different years) - it shows them as being the same year, even though the data *is* different:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

Curiouser and curiouser - using the NumberFormat "dd mmm" like so:

```
//monthField.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"; with this, they all show one year, even when the range spans two years
//monthField.NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy"; this shows a combination, such as "16 Jan 2016" and "15 Sep 2016"
monthField.NumberFormat = "dd mmm";
```

...did give me different years, but they are ordered wrong (16 coming before 15):

[image]

### UPDATE 3

Even bizarresquer is when I generate a 13-month report, thus having two of the same months (but of different years); In this scenario, the 2016 months are in order, followed by the 2015 months, as before, except for the doubled month, where the 2015 year rightly but bizarrely (based on the behavior of the rest of the month labels) comes first:

[image]

### UPDATE 4

I have tried every combination of the following, and they all fail in one way or another:

Providing data to the source sheet that the PivotTable uses - either in format "YY-MMM" (like "15-Sep") or "YYYY-MMM" (like "2015-Sep"):

```
monthYearCell.Value2 = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(MonthYear);
```

-or:

```
string _prependedCentury = "20" + MonthYear;
monthYearCell.Value2 = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(_prependedCentury); //MonthYear);
```

And then applying various NumberFormats:

```
//monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yy";
monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yyyy";
//monthField.NumberFormat = "yyyy MMM";
//monthField.NumberFormat = "yyyy-MMM";
//monthField.NumberFormat = "dd mmm";
```

There must be some combination of data format and NumberFormat property that will show the values correctly and in the correct order, but I haven't hit upon it yet.

### UPDATE 5

If the source data is in the format YYYYMM (such as "201509" and "201510") and the NumberFormat used by the pivot table is "MMM yy", both columns (Sep 2015 and Oct 2015) display as "Sep 51".

Comment: does it help if you say: var monthField = "20"+pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr"); because I am wondering if right now it thinks 15 Jan is Jan 15, 2016

Comment: Aisle czech it out.

Comment: It fails to generate the file, and the exception I get is, "Exception message: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Orientation'"

Comment: hmmm. I guess I do not know enough about setting the value of monthField. Still if you can figure that out, I am still wondering about what it thinks the date is. If my hunch is right, if you set NumberFormat to "dd mmm yyyy", I bet you see the 15s and 16s there.

Comment: Aisle czech that out, too...

Comment: Interesting; the labels are now "16 Jan 2016", "16 Feb 2016", "15 Sep 2016", etc. I will try "dd mmm" now, just for grins.

Comment: Then the solution is going to look like after you set things originally to say something like monthField.Value = "20"+pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr").Value; but I cannot commit to the specifics.

Comment: That last is what I tried earlier at your suggestion which failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126356/discussion-between-jeremy-kahan-and-b-clay-shannon).

Comment: Any chance you can upload this spreadsheet (or one that demonstrates the issue) to DropBox or G-Drive?  I have several thoughts, but I can't cement any of them without seeing the issue in action.

Comment: Clay -- my initial guess, and it's just a guess, is that "Dec 15" might be "12/15/2016."  It's MMM DD, but when you change the format to MMM YY it appears that the year changes when in fact you might be showing a different date element

Comment: @Hambone: I put it on skydrive here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!As6s8JUvZlDBh7hvuVsEgqJ2_GvgkA

Comment: Looking at the file, it does appear to be a date formatting thing.  "15-Sep" shows as "9/15/2016."  If I change each of the 9/15/2016 to 9/1/2015 and then refresh the pivot table, it appears the way you want (I think) as Sep 2015.  Then, if I sort the Months on "Oldest First" the "Sep 2015" moves all the way to the left

Comment: It let me save the updated file!  How cool is that?  Check it out and let me know...

Comment: I would need a way to programmatically change it to the right format; thanks, but I finally figure it out - my auto-answer is below. If you want to make an answer based on that, so that I can accept one for the bounty, go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

Converted the source data YYYYMM vals to MM/1/YYYY:

```
// These come in as "YYYYMM" values (such as "201509"); need them to be 9/1/2016 and suchlike
private string ConvertToMMDDYYYY(string monthYear)
{
    string YYYY = monthYear.Substring(0, 4);
    string MM = monthYear.Substring(4, 2);
    return string.Format("{0}/1/{1}", MM, YYYY);
}
```

Used them on the PivotTable this way:

```
var monthField = pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr");
monthField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yy";
```